# x-Axis not working because I'm not using correctly moment.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs

I'm trying to plot some info, and my `x-axis` are time. For this objective I'm using, `chart.js` and `moment.js` but I'm having some problems to convert this time to a label.

My code is:

```
var sData = {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset1',
        data: [{ x: '09:00', y: 88 }, { x: '09:10', y: 89 }, { x: '09:13', y: 86 }, { x: '09:23', y: 86 },
            { x: '09:26', y: 85}, { x: '09:29', y: 83 }]
        }, {
        label: 'Dataset2',
        data: [{ x: '09:02', y: 88 }, { x: '09:13', y: 89 }, { x: '09:14', y: 86 }, { x: '09:20', y: 86 },
            { x: '09:24', y: 85 }, { x: '09:29', y: 83 }]
    }]
}

sData.datasets[0].data = formatData(sData.datasets[0].data)
sData.datasets[1].data = formatData(sData.datasets[1].data)

function formatData(oldData) {
    var newData = []
    for (var i = 0; i < oldData.length; i++) {
        var currentData = {}
        currentData.x = moment(oldData[i].x, "HH:mm").format('HH:mm')
        currentData.y = oldData[i].y
        newData.push(currentData)
    }
    return newData
  }

var data = sData

var options = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
        }]
    },
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            title: function(tooltipItem, data){
                return moment(tooltipItem[0].label).format('HH:mm')
            }
        }
    }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('bateria_graf');
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

I think the problem is that I'm not formatting correctly the time, but I don't know how to solve it. Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is located in your `formatData` function. Using `moment`, you correctly parse the time but then you `format` it back to its original `string` value. The solution is to no longer call `format`.

```
currentData.x = moment(oldData[i].x, "HH:mm");
```

And the whole thing:

```js
var sData = {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset1',
        data: [{ x: '09:00', y: 88 }, { x: '09:10', y: 89 }, { x: '09:13', y: 86 }, { x: '09:23', y: 86 },
            { x: '09:26', y: 85}, { x: '09:29', y: 83 }]
        }, {
        label: 'Dataset2',
        data: [{ x: '09:02', y: 88 }, { x: '09:13', y: 89 }, { x: '09:14', y: 86 }, { x: '09:20', y: 86 },
            { x: '09:24', y: 85 }, { x: '09:29', y: 83 }]
    }]
}

sData.datasets[0].data = formatData(sData.datasets[0].data)
sData.datasets[1].data = formatData(sData.datasets[1].data)

function formatData(oldData) {
    var newData = []
    for (var i = 0; i < oldData.length; i++) {
        var currentData = {}
        currentData.x = moment(oldData[i].x, "HH:mm")
        currentData.y = oldData[i].y
        newData.push(currentData)
    }
    return newData
}

var options = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
        }]
    },
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            title: (tooltipItem, data) => moment(tooltipItem[0].label).format('HH:mm')            
        }
    }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('bateria_graf').getContext('2d');
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: sData,
    options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.1.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="bateria_graf"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I have one more question (I added in my post because it's more clean) and I would be grateful if you can answer it. Basically is, why it's showing the date of today in `x-axis`? Thank you again!

Comment: @NEA: It would have been cleaner to accept my answer and post a new question with a runnable code snippet. This makes it easier to provide a concise answer.

Comment: Ok, I do it. Sorry :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737280/why-are-changing-the-time-value-of-my-axis-moment-js   :)